# How to activate a Windows Server 2019 domain controller

Tags: domain, windows-server-2019, domain-registration, activation

So the (lone) server in a very small (2 person) office was activated with an evaluation key and configured (very extensively) - awaiting budget for the license.  Only to find out that it must be demoted from DC and another machine take on the role *just to enter a license*.

So, effectively, stuck. Seems nuts given there surely must be literally millions of single server small offices. But here we are.

Please no "did you do your homework/RTFM" slams. That's why I'm asking: this did not come up in anything I did do.

Answer (score 1):

Add another DC temporarily. Demote the current DC, activate it, then promote it to domain controller again.

Comment: As I said in the question - there's only one server.  That was the whole point of this question - i.e. is there some hack or workaround known by somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You [can't change it to retail as per Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started/upgrade-conversion-options#convert-an-evaluation-version-to-a-retail-version)

> If the server is an Active Directory domain controller, you can't convert it to a retail version. See Upgrade Domain Controllers to Windows Server for important information.

Your best bet at this stage is to set up a new server, promote it, move all roles over and demote the old one.